# C++ Variable number of async tasks

Tags: c++, c++17

In this example i have 3 tasks which should run parallel. This works realy well. But now the number of tasks is variable. How can i handle that? I tried something like vector of lambda expressions but that doesn't worked. Thanks for helping !

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <future>
 #include "myclass.h"

 #define N  3

int main()
{
  // Create instances
  std::vector<myclass*> instances;
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      myclass *mc = new myclass();
      instances.push_back(mc);
  }

  auto f0 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){
      bool finish = false;
      while(!finish){
          if(instances[0]->do() != 0) finish = true;
      }
  });

  auto f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){
      bool finish = false;
      while(!finish){
          if(instances[1]->do() != 0) finish = true;
      }
  });

  auto f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){
      bool finish = false;
      while(!finish){
          if(instances[2]->do() != 0) finish = true;
      }
  });

  f0.wait(); f1.wait(); f2.wait();

  // delete instances
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      delete instances[i];
  }

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: how about a vector of futures? (the things that `std::async` returns)

Comment: `std::vector<myclass> instances(N);` would avoid manual memory management...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop and create a new lambda with different binding context every iteration:

```
    std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks;
    for (auto& instance : instances) {
        tasks.push_back(
            std::async(std::launch::async, [&, instance]() {
                bool finish = false;
                while (!finish) {
                    if (instance->do() != 0) finish = true;
                }
            })
        );
    }
    // wait for all tasks to finish
    for (auto& task : tasks) task.wait();
```

Answer (score 3):

You may consider use `std::function`, a demo program:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<std::function<void()>> vec;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    vec.emplace_back(
        [i = i] { std::cout << "hi" + std::to_string(i) << std::endl; });
  }

  std::vector<std::future<void>> futs;
  for (const auto& f : vec) {
    futs.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, f));
  }

  for (auto& f : futs) f.wait();
  return 0;
}
```

Generally `std::async` is not suitable for large programs, we may consider use some thread pool based frameworks like:

- tbb
- folly
- boost-asio
- poco